# Read input and print to table with multi-line wrap ability

Tags: bash

I have stdin that looks like this:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
2. This is a test, this is only a test.  Do not adjust your television.  Blah, blah, blah; yak, yak yak; foo, bar, baz, qux.
3. Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
```

I'd like to be able to organize this in a table on the command line — **with  the** the description wrapping and continuing to appropriate column on the next line:

```
 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo...
 2. This is a test, this is only a test.  Do not adjust your television.  Blah,
    blah, blah; yak, yak yak; foo, bar, baz, qux.
 3. Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent,
    a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that
    all men are created equal.
```

Either hard or soft-wrap will do.

Anyone know of a way to this this.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest but this will work.

```
$ cat input
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
2. This is a test, this is only a test.  Do not adjust your television.  Blah, blah, blah; yak, yak yak; foo, bar, baz, qux.
3. Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
$ cat input | fold -s -w 78| awk '/^[[:digit:]]+\./{a=length($1); print; next} {sub(/^ +/, ""); printf "%*s%s\n", a+1, " ", $0}'
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
   consequat.
2. This is a test, this is only a test.  Do not adjust your television.
   Blah, blah, blah; yak, yak yak; foo, bar, baz, qux.
3. Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this
   continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the
   proposition that all men are created equal.
```

I gave `fold` a size slightly less than the actual window so that the added padding didn't push a line off the end of the window (and wrap again).